# Como mudar para português o campo data no Materialize

Tags: materialize

Uso o materialize, e coloquei o campo data com a classe datepicker:

```
<div class="input-field col s6">
    <input type="date" name='vencimento' class="datepicker">
    <label for="vencimento">Vencimento</label>
</div>
```

O quadro que aparece vem no padrão inglês, é possível colocá-lo em pt-BR?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Na hora de inicializar o script js coloque assim:

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
    monthsFull: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
    monthsShort: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
    weekdaysFull: ['Domingo', 'Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sabádo'],
    weekdaysShort: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sab'],
    today: 'Hoje',
    clear: 'Limpar',
    close: 'Pronto',
    labelMonthNext: 'Próximo mês',
    labelMonthPrev: 'Mês anterior',
    labelMonthSelect: 'Selecione um mês',
    labelYearSelect: 'Selecione um ano',
    selectMonths: true, 
    selectYears: 15 
    });
```

Comment: Entrei nessa pergunta querendo responder, mas essa resposta já está correta. O autor deveria marcar como resposta certa.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  format:'yyyy-mm-dd',
i18n:{
  months: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
  monthsShort: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
  weekdays: ['Domingo', 'Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sabádo'],
  weekdaysAbbrev: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sab'],
  today: 'Hoje',
  clear: 'Limpar',
  close: 'Pronto',
  labelMonthNext: 'Próximo mês',
  labelMonthPrev: 'Mês anterior',
  labelMonthSelect: 'Selecione um mês',
  labelYearSelect: 'Selecione um ano',
  selectMonths: true,
  selectYears: 15,
  cancel: 'Cancelar',
  clear: 'Limpar'
}
});
```

Comment: Essa foi a que funcionou para mim. Só que onde está weekdaysAbbrev tem que ser weekdaysShort